# Most efficient way to store values in separate bash variables

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I was wondering what's the most efficient way to store values in different columns in separate variables

This is what I'm doing right now but I'm not sure if there's a better solution:

```
ITEM="5.8  1.4 2345 user123 23:27 vim test.c"
CPU="$(echo "$ITEM" | awk '{print $1}')"
MEM="$(echo "$ITEM" | awk '{print $2}')"
PID="$(echo "$ITEM" | awk '{print $3}')"
USER="$(echo "$ITEM" | awk '{print $4}')"
TIME="$(echo "$ITEM" | awk '{print $5}')"
ARGS="$(echo "$ITEM" | awk '{ for(i=6;i<=NF;++i) printf("%s ", $i) }')"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is the natural choice. All uppercase names are reserved for the shell, so best to stick to lowercase.

```
items=(5.8  1.4 2345 user123 23:27 vim test.c)

cpu=${items[0]}
mem=${items[1]}
pid=${items[2]}
user=${items[3]}
time=${items[4]}
args=${items[@]:5}
```

If you were starting with a string you could easily store items into multiple variables with `read`.

```
read -r cpu mem pid user time args <<< "5.8  1.4 2345 user123 23:27 vim test.c"
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to create these many variables, I believe that is why arrays are there in use, try:

```
ITEM="5.8  1.4 2345 user123 23:27 vim test.c"
arr=($ITEM)
```

To access the items from this array you could use then like:

```
CPU="${arr[0]}"
echo "$CPU"
5.8
MEM="${arr[1]}"
echo "$MEM"
1.4
PID="${arr[2]}"
echo "$PID"
2345
USER="${arr[3]}"
echo "$USER"
user123
TIME="${arr[4]}"
echo "TIME"
TIME
ARGS="${arr[@]:5}"
echo "$ARGS"
vim test.c
```

***EDIT:*** Adding solution with `read` too here.

```
read -a arr <<<"$ITEM"
```

Comment: It's better to use `read` here. `arr=($item)` is subject to pathname expansion. You can disable it with `set -f` though :)

Comment: @PesaThe, sure done with adding solution in `read` too now, cheers !

Comment: Nice. Add `-r` and it's perfect :)

Comment: @PesaThe, cool, I believe Sir John has already added that. Or want me to add in current solution itself to it?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, for future reference, `declare -p` is a great way to display variable (including array) contents in bash, rather than the collection of `echo` lines (which could be replaced with `printf`). It's also worth noting that handled this way, a wildcard within the string might be expanded into unexpected array content.  Try: `s="/bin/c*"; a=($s); declare -p a`

Comment: @ghoti, great example sir, thank you for letting know.